# Angular ng-click not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="stat in stats"> 
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" ng-click="hideShow=(hideShow ? false : true); vm.charts(stat.jobId)">
            <div class="card card-stats">
                <div class="card-header" data-background-color="orange">
                    <i class="material-icons">content_copy</i>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p class="category">{{stat.market}} {{stat.line}} </p>
                    <h3 class="title">{{stat.considered}}
                        <small>Rec</small>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="stats">
                        <i class="material-icons">date_range</i> {{stat.updated_at}} 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="hideShow">
    test
    <div ng-repeat="chart in charts">
        {{chart}}
        {{chart.data.jobId}}
        {{chart.jobId}} {{chart.line}} {{chart.market}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the `div ng-if="hideShow"` never displays on the screen. If I place the last piece of code `<div ng-if="hideShow"></div>` inside the first `<div ng-repeat="stat in stats">` then it will display... But I want it to be a complete unrelated div.

How can I have an unrelated div display once the following div is clicked:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" ng-click="hideShow=(hideShow ? false : true); vm.charts(stat.jobId)">
```

Following the controller for this:

```
// Keep things clean and sane
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('sigmaApp')
        .controller('statisticsController', statisticsController);

    function statisticsController($scope, $state, $location,$document, $mdToast, recordService) {

        // List out our members & methods
        var vm = this;

        //my methods
        vm.closeView = closeView;
        vm.showToast = showToast;
        vm.charts = charts;
        $scope.jobs = [];
        $scope.stats = [];
        $scope.charts = [];
        $scope.hideShow = false;

        recordService.getJobs().then(function(jobs){

            for(var i = 0; i<jobs.data.length; i++){ 
                if(jobs.data[i].type === 'parent')
                    $scope.jobs.push(jobs.data[i]);
            }

            for(var i=0; i<$scope.jobs.length; i++){
                recordService.stats($scope.jobs[i].id).then(function(stats){
                    $scope.stats.push(stats.data[0]);
                });
            }

            console.log($scope.stats);

            for(var i=0; i<$scope.stats.length; i++){
                console.log($scope.stats[i]);
            }

        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

        function charts(id){
            console.log('build charts for job: '+id);
            var stat;
            for (var i=0; i<$scope.stats.length; i++){
                if ( $scope.stats[i].jobId == id){
                    stat = $scope.stats[i];
                }
            }
            $scope.charts = stat;
        }

        function closeView() {
            $state.go('app.records');
        }

        function showToast(message) {
            $mdToast.show(
                    $mdToast.simple()
                        .content(message)
                        .position('top, right')
                        .hideDelay(5000)
                ); // END toast.show
        } // END showToast

    } // END 

})(); // END iffy
```

Comment: Have you tried to initialize the value of "hideShow"?

Comment: I haven't. But if the div is inside the other one it works.. so I dont think that is the problem...

Comment: I believe you can simplify `(hideShow ? false : true)` to `!hideShow`

Comment: I think you should try. When the div is inside your repeat I think "hideShow" is scoping to the variables that you have defined inside your repeater. Outside "hideShow" isn't defined. I will quickly mention defining variables or logic inside your HTML is bad practice and causes hard to debug issues like this.

Comment: I don't see how `hideShow` can be true if you never initialized it. It would be a false value and the div won't show

Comment: @Mickers How can I declare it?

Comment: @Huangism the idea is that the div doesn't show until I click the other one..

Comment: You would need to post the js code that runs this. Probably the component or controller. Maybe your `hideShow` was declared at the wrong spot, hard to say

Comment: As @Huangism pointed out you should initialize hideShow in your controller or component's $onInit method if you're using angularJs 1.5.6+. $scope.hideShow = true/false;

Comment: @Huangism editted

Comment: I haven't used angular in awhile but don't you need to define `$scope.hideShow` to use it in the way you want?

Comment: @Huangism after adding it to my controller still doesn't display. Updated question

Comment: Does it work if you set it to true? as in does it display when the page loads? If not then your js code is probably not responsible for the html part. Also put `hideShow=(hideShow ? false : true)` in a scope function so you know you are modifying the only scope hideShow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting your visibility of your div to a primitive type (boolean). Through the magic of prototypal inheritance, the scope value you are modifying via

```
ng-click="hideShow=(hideShow ? false : true)
```

is the child scope being created from the ng-repeat directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="stat in stats">
```

Therefore the value is being shadowed/hidden and you are not modifying the correct value. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482). That is why the div will work hide/show when you move the div **within** the scope of ng-repeat, but it will not work outside the scope of ng-repeat.

To work around this you can utilize the '.' notation and stick your visibility to an object's property.

So in your controller you initialize a new object literal with the boolean flag.

```
 $scope.div = {};
 $scope.div.hideShow = false;
```

And then modify your click event to modify this object

```
 ng-click="div.hideShow = !div.hideShow"
```

and then modify your visibility via

```
<div ng-if="div.hideShow">
    test
    <div ng-repeat="chart in charts">
        {{chart}}
        {{chart.data.jobId}}
        {{chart.jobId}} {{chart.line}} {{chart.market}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: much appreciated.